# Creating indices for 4-dimensional numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I would like to know the systematic way of accessing either 1st, 2nd, or 3rd elements in each column from an array looking like this.

```
array([[[[0.23137255, 0.24313726, 0.24705882],
         [0.16862746, 0.18039216, 0.1764706 ],
         [0.19607843, 0.1882353 , 0.16862746],
         ...,
         [0.61960787, 0.5176471 , 0.42352942],
         [0.59607846, 0.49019608, 0.4       ],
         [0.5803922 , 0.4862745 , 0.40392157]],

        [[0.0627451 , 0.07843138, 0.07843138],
         [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.07058824, 0.03137255, 0.        ],

 ...,
         [0.7019608 , 0.69411767, 0.6784314 ],
         [0.6431373 , 0.6431373 , 0.63529414],
         [0.6392157 , 0.6392157 , 0.6313726 ]]]], dtype=float32)
```

with the shape of (50000, 32, 32, 3)
These are pixel values for 50000 images. The first index indicates the image number, the second and third the x and y positions, and the fourth index the RGB color channel.  So basically I want only red, green, blue color at a time. i.e.

```
red = [0.23137255, 0.16862746, 0.19607843, .., 0.6431373, 0.6392157]
green = [0.24313726, 0.18039216, 0.1882353, .., 0.6431373, 0.6392157]
blue = [0.24705882, 0.1764706, 0.16862746, .., 0.63529414, 0.6313726]
```

I tried to use something like tf.gather_nd but am open to other ways.

Comment: can you make an example of what should it look in 2D? It's not clear what you want

Comment: `arr[:,:,:,0]` is a (50000,32,32) array with just the 'red' values.  Or `arr[...,0]`

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj !!  Why didn't I think of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still unclear to me but here is a way to access either 1st, 2nd, or 3rd elements in each column from a 4-D array:

**For accessing the RGB value of the pixel at x and y of an image of your dataset :**

```
my_4D_array = [[[[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(32)]for x in range(32)]for x in range(50000)]
print(my_4D_array[0][0][0][0]) #show the red pixel(RGB) value of the pixel at x = 0 and y = 0 of the 1st img of your dataset
```

edit: original poster said he need a solution with less loop so it's can run on jupiter notebook

```
import numpy as np    

my_4D_array  = np.zeros(50000*32*32*3)
my_4D_array  = np.reshape(my_4D_array, (50000,32,32,3))
print(my_4D_array[0][0][0][0]) #show the red pixel(RGB) value of the pixel at x = 0 and y = 0 of the 1st img of your dataset
```

you have a 4-D array full of 0.0

Comment: Thanks! This would work but causes memory problem (I am working on a Jupyter notebook.) Do you have any suggestions without using several loops?

Comment: Maybe you can use google collab to have a notebook with free powerful cloud computing.

Comment: I heard google collab works almost the same way as jupyter notebook.  Thanks for your suggestion.